# Using a JSX Component inside a TSX Component cannot compile without throwing an error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

So I had a typescript-react component called  `ContractExpenses` and I am using a JSX component inside it called DynamicSelector, however I get an error as follows

[image]

This is the code for my `<DynamicSelector/>` component

```
const DynamicSelector = ({ query, variables, ...staticSelectorProps }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(query, { variables });
  if (error) return null;
  let list = [];
  if (data) {
    const key = Object.keys(data)[0];
    list = get(data, key, []);
  }
  return (
    <StaticSelector loading={loading} items={list} {...staticSelectorProps} />
  );
};

export default DynamicSelector;
```

Is there any way, I can avoid such errors, it is killing me to use typescript because i have to convert all the children (and their children!) to typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `variables` prop optional like, give some default value to it.

```
const DynamicSelector = ({ query, variables = {}, ...staticSelectorProps }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(query, { variables });
  if (error) return null;
  let list = [];
  if (data) {
    const key = Object.keys(data)[0];
    list = get(data, key, []);
  }
  return (
    <StaticSelector loading={loading} items={list} {...staticSelectorProps} />
  );
};

export default DynamicSelector;
```

Because `Typescript` expects you to pass `variables` Prop , either pass it or make it some default or make it optional by making an interface.

Like this

```
export interface DynamicSelectorProps {
  query: any;
  variables?: any;
}


const DynamicSelector: FC<DynamicSelectorProps> = ({ query, variables, ...staticSelectorProps }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(query, { variables });
  if (error) return null;
  let list = [];
  if (data) {
    const key = Object.keys(data)[0];
    list = get(data, key, []);
  }
  return (
    <StaticSelector loading={loading} items={list} {...staticSelectorProps} />
  );
};

export default DynamicSelector;
```

**Edit**

passing `undefined` as the default value for props is better since, it will be ignored by the component most of the time, resulting in fewer bugs, if any.

Comment: The default props idea was decent and worked without making me refactor the entire heirarchy in typescript..I think passing `undefined` is better and will result in a fewer bugs

Comment: always keep default value to something so it does not breaks.